# doInbackground of asyncktask is not called

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This url is executed when a button is clicked

```
new HttpAsyncTasks().execute("http://www.demo.com/xyz");
```

this is the asynctask for the above execution

```
private class HttpAsyncTasks extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return POSTS(urls[0]);

    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //call main activity activity upon successful registration


        Intent callMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(callMain);

   }
}
```

The doInbackground of the above never gets executed but the onPostExecute method does.

this is the POSTS method called in doInbackground

```
public  String POSTS(String url){

     InputStream inputStream = null;
       String result = "";
       try {

           // 1. create HttpClient
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

           // 2. make POST request to the given URL
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

           String json = "";


           // 3. build jsonObject
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
           jsonObject.accumulate("xyz", "xyz");
           jsonObject.accumulate("amount", "800");
           jsonObject.accumulate("demo", "demo");
           jsonObject.accumulate("demo2", demo2);

           // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
           json = jsonObject.toString();

           // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
           // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

           // 5. set json to StringEntity
           StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

           // 6. set httpPost Entity
           httpPost.setEntity(se);

           // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
           httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
           httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

           // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

           // 9. receive response as inputStream
           inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

           // 10. convert inputstream to string
           if(inputStream != null)
               result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
           else
               result = "Did not work!";

       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
       }

       // 11. return result
       return result;
   }
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Just checking. Are you sure the POST() methos id not called and the case is not that the said function return null?

Comment: It is not because I added a Toast in the method. which never get executed

Comment: try logging or debugging, i m quite sure that it is getting executed

Comment: But why is the toast not showing

Comment: coz you are in a non-ui thread

Comment: The toast in the onPost executes

Comment: So how do I get it into a ui thread

Comment: if it's in onPostExecute then it should show, try using activity context

Comment: where would I use activity context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112879/discussion-between-sarthak-mittal-and-blaze).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this with way. It's checking your POSTS method.
If toast show empty line, your error in POSTS method on WebProcess.

```
private class HttpAsyncTasks extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String myResult="check";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try
        {
            myResult = POSTS(urls[0]);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
        return myResult;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        /* other codes */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your POSTS(urls[0]) call must be giving an exception and when it does the rest of the code is skipped and it bypasses your toast. Try removing exception you can find it in logcat.